# How can I extract metadata from an MP3 file?

Tags: android, mp3

I've got the file name of an MP3 file. How can I extract metadata, like artist, album, album image,... from this MP3 file?

Answer (score 20):

Try this for API level 10 or greater:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(filePath);

String albumName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
```

And so on...

For more [help](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html).

Comment: An answer that [earned a badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat?page=1) ought to be better than a "try this" answer. E.g., a documentation reference could be added. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11328221/edit), not here in comments ([without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011) "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
byte[] artBytes = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
if(artBytes != null)
{
    //InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(artBytes, 0, artBytes.length);
    bSongImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
else
{
    bSongImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cmp));
}
```

The 'else' is for not having an embedded image in the audio file.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
MetaDataRetriever m_metaRetriever = new MetaDataRetriever();
m_metaRetriever.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, uriSound);
```

The input parameter of the `setDataSource` method should include the context also. Else it throws illegalArgument Exception.

Comment: Does the exception (name) actually start with a lowercase letter? What is its actual name?