# Read mp3 metadata from assets folder

Tags: android, mp3, metadata, android-assets

I have an app with some mp3 files stored inside a subfolder of assets folder. 
I obtain list of files in this way

```
context.getAssets().list("audio");
```

and results show it inside a listview.
By doing this, what i see is a list of mp3 filenames. Now i don't want show filenames, but associated metadata for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. 
First get the file path as shown here

[How to pass a file path which is in assets folder to File(String path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820142/how-to-pass-a-file-path-which-is-in-assets-folder-to-filestring-path)

And then get metadata of audio as shown here

[How to extract metadata from mp3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327954/how-to-extract-metadata-from-mp3)

Comment: but in this way i copy file from asset folder to another folder into device storage, occupying double disk space. So if i have 20 MB of mp3 inside assets, after copy i occupy another 20 mb of storage, and i would avoid this

Comment: After getting metadata delete the file and pick next one and so one ;-)

Comment: This isn't the best approach, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Copying the file to disk isn't necessary. [MediaMetadataRetriever](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) and [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) both offer a [setDataSource method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#setDataSource%28java.io.FileDescriptor,%20long,%20long%29) that takes a FileDescriptor as an argument:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();\
// or MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

String path = "audio";

String [] files  = context.getAssets().list(path);

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    String file = path + "/" + files[i];

    AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(file);

    metaRetriver.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());

    String album = metaRetriver.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
    String artist = metaRetriver.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
    String gener = metaRetriver.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);

    afd.close();
}

metaRetriver.release();
```

Answer (score 0):

By metadata means name, title, time etc data if you want then you need to use **MediaMetadataRetriever** class to do so..

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriver.setDataSource("path of song");
String album = metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);

String artist = metaRetriver
    .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
String gener=metaRetriver
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
```

Similarly you can extract other data also..
Hope it will help you.